Who introduced the notion of metalanguage in formal logic, and what was the rationale at the time?
Who first used the notion of metalanguage in formal logic, and what was the rationale offered to justify the move at the time?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Hilbert in the 1920s introduced the concept of meta-mathematics.

The hierarchy of languages was defined by Carnap (1934) and the concept of meta-language is defined in Tarski (1936)

See also your previous post.

The rationale was getting out of the Liar paradox, see IEP:"Tarski claimed that the crucial, unacceptable assumption of the formal version of the Liar Argument is the self-reference allowed because... language contains its own global truth predicate... Tarski then took on the project of discovering how close he could come to having a well-defined truth predicate within a classical formal language without actually having one. That project, his hierarchy of meta-languages, is also his key idea for solving the Liar Paradox."

Metalogic is considered to have been founded by Tarski in 1930:

Tarski, A. (1930). Fundamentale Begriffe der Merthodologie der deduktiven Wissenschaften (Fundamental Concepts of the Methodology of Deductive Sciences). Comptes Rendus des séances de la Société des Sciences et des Lettres de Varsovie, Classe III, 23, 361–404.

English translation in Tarski, A. (1956), pp. 61–109:

Tarski, A. (1956). Logic, Semantics, Metamathematics. Papers from 1923 to 1938. Oxford
Clarendon: Press. (Reprinted in 1983 by Indianapolis: Hackett Publishn Company).

